# an app is not installing and fails with vcredist_x86_2013 Using Wine 3.8

Tags: software-installation, wine

During installation of a windows app using Wine 3.8, the app tries to install vcredist_x86_2013 along the way and after some time installation reverts everything and says it could not install the app. The process of installation fails after the followings status:
[image]

I installed  vcredist using:

```
winetricks -q vcrun2013
```

Then, I tried to install the program again. It tried to install vcredist again as shown in the screenshot. But it again failed to install saying it could not install the program. Is there a way to bypass vcredist installation or give access to the installer to install vcredist? How can I fix this? Is there any workaround to install the program? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a system problem. I needed to reinstall Wine. First, make sure you delete all wine related files and its dependencies. Then install the new version (3.8 in my case). In `winecfg`, set `gdiplus` to `native then buildin`. Install `vcrun2013` by `winetricks vcrun2013`. Then running the setup.exe will install the program with no issues.